# latest Dbeaver, connect to postgresql database with md5 password

Tags: postgresql, md5, dbeaver

When I try to connect database via DBeaver I get an error 'FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username"'. After some research, I think the problem in password encryption difference between the database which uses md5 and DBeaver driver which probably uses SCRAM.

How can I force DBeaver to use md5 instead of SCRAM? I'm using the latest version of DBeaver.

Comment: If DBeaver is capable of SCRAM, it will also be capable of md5, and will use the method the server tells it to use.  The real problem is something else, and the db log file will probably give you a clue.